# Conditionally unset checkout field in woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

How can I conditionally unset the other two fields from server side and remove the required validation from it?

Here is how the form looks like:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
function bs_filter_checkout_fields($fields){
    $fields['billing'] = array(

        'add_type' => array(
            'type' => 'radio',
            'label' => __( 'Address Type' ),
            'options' => array( 'house' => __( 'House' ), 'building' => __( 'Building' ), 'office' => __( 'Office' ) ),
            'required' => true
                ),
        'add_house_name' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'required'      => true,
            'placeholder' => __( 'House Name/Number' ),
            'label' => __( 'House Name/Number' )
        ),
        'add_building_name' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'required'  => true,
            'placeholder' => __( 'Building Name/Number' ),
            'label' => __( 'Building Name/Number' )
        ),
        'add_office_name' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'required'  => true,
            'placeholder' => __( 'Office Name/Number' ),
            'label' => __( 'Office Name/Number' )
        ),
    );
return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'bs_filter_checkout_fields' );
function bs_conditional_scripts() {
    wc_enqueue_js( "
        $( '#add_type_house' ).change( function () {

            if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                $('#add_building_name_field').hide();
                $('#add_office_name_field').hide();
                $( '#add_house_name_field' ).show();
            }

        } ).change();

    $( '#add_type_building' ).change( function () {

        if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
            $( '#add_house_name_field' ).hide();
            $('#add_office_name_field').hide();
            $('#add_building_name_field').show();
        }

    } ).change();


    $( '#add_type_office' ).change( function () {

        if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
            $( '#add_house_name_field' ).hide();
            $('#add_building_name_field').hide();
            $('#add_office_name_field').show();
        }

    } ).change();
    " );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bs_conditional_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function bs_filter_checkout_fields($fields){ 
                     $fields['billing'] = array(
                          'add_type' => array(
                                'type' => 'radio',
                                'label' => __( 'Address Type' ),
                                'options' => array( 'house' => __( 'House' ), 'building' => __( 'Building' ), 'office' => __( 'Office' ) ),
                                'required' => true
                                ),
                            'add_house_name' => array(
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'required'      => true,
                                'placeholder' => __( 'House Name/Number' ),
                                'label' => __( 'House Name/Number' )
                                ),
                            'add_building_name' => array(
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'required'  => true,
                                'placeholder' => __( 'Building Name/Number' ),
                                'label' => __( 'Building Name/Number' )
                                ),
                            'add_office_name' => array(
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'required'  => true,
                                'placeholder' => __( 'Office Name/Number' ),
                                'label' => __( 'Office Name/Number' )
                                ),
                            );
        if( true ){ // pass conditional statement here
          unset($fields['billing']['add_house_name']);  //  remove field
          $fields['billing']['add_building_name']['required']   = false; // remove required validation
        }                   
        return $fields;
        }
```