# How Remove Required Validation at Conditional Checkout Field at Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, field, checkout

I use     conditional checkout fields as given at [Conditionally unset checkout field in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099213/conditionally-unset-checkout-field-in-woocommerce/43172109#43172109) .
But, It doesn't  remove required validation fields?
How can I pass conditional statement within "if (true)" to remove required validation ?
 At the other words, how can I check which option is selected? 
Regards

```
 if( true ){ // pass conditional statement here
     unset($fields['billing']['add_house_name']);  //  remove field
     $fields['billing']['add_building_name']['required']   = false; //            remove required validation
        }                   
        return $fields;
```

Comment: You can use condition something like this:

if($fields['billing']['add_house_name'] ==true)
{
unset($fields['billing']['add_house_name']);  //  remove field
     $fields['billing']['add_building_name']['required']   = false; //     
}

Answer (score 1):

You can override checkout fields using this code:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
     $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = false;

     return $address_fields;
}
```

You can add this hook to a condition where you check inputs based on which you want to trigger validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I could'n't know how I can create the condition. Because I want to use it to remove of at fields depending on radio button selection.  I trigger it via;  ' wc_enqueue_js( "
        $( '#faturabilgi_bireysel' ).change( function () {

            if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                $('#billing_firma_field').hide(); $( '#billing_tckn_field' ).show(); '  I want to remove required validation of "billing_firma_field" , but how can I insert your code here? Regards

Comment: This solution will help you achieve your functionality. Have a look at it: https://wordimpress.com/create-conditional-checkout-fields-woocommerce/